# How to loop through columns and store certain values from each column into their own variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and am sorting through data. I am trying  to go through columns and pull out values from each column and  store them in a variable. I have done this for another  project by just doing it separately for each  column. This is the code that I have  used before and it works, but now I have 36 columns  I need to go through and VBA crashes when I try and do  this for all 36. I  want to find a way to  loop through the columns that way maybe VBA won't crash.

```
Sub DepolarizedPotentialValues()

    Dim ChartCells1 As Range
    Dim Count1 As Range
    Dim Cells1 As Range
    Dim Number1 As Range
    Dim Columns1 As Range
    Dim xrng As Range
    Dim Temp1 As Range
    Dim Temp2 As Range
    Dim Temp3 As Range

    DataSheet.Activate

    Set Number1 = Range("AF2")
    Set Cells1 = Range("AF2", Range("AF2").End(xlDown))
    Set ChartCells1 = Range("AF1:AF2").Offset(0, -12)

    For Each Count1 In Cells1
        If Count1.Value <> Number1 Then
            Set ChartCells1 = Union(ChartCells1, Count1.Offset(0, -12))
            Set Number1 = Count1
        End If
    Next Count1

    Dim ChartCells2 As Range
    Dim Count2 As Range
    Dim Cells2 As Range
    Dim Number2 As Range
    Dim Columns2 As Range

    Set Number2 = Range("AG2")
    Set Cells2 = Range("AG2", Range("AG2").End(xlDown))
    Set ChartCells2 = Range("AG1:AG2").Offset(0, -12)

    For Each Count2 In Cells2
        If Count2.Value <> Number2 Then
            Set ChartCells2 = Union(ChartCells2, Count2.Offset(0, -12))
            Set Number2 = Count2
        End If
    Next Count2

    Dim ChartCells3 As Range
    Dim Count3 As Range
    Dim Cells3 As Range
    Dim Number3 As Range
    Dim Columns3 As Range

    Set Number3 = Range("AH2")
    Set Cells3 = Range("AH2", Range("AH2").End(xlDown))
    Set ChartCells3 = Range("AH1:AH2").Offset(0, -12)

    For Each Count3 In Cells3
        If Count3.Value <> Number3 Then
            Set ChartCells3 = Union(ChartCells3, Count3.Offset(0, -12))
            Set Number3 = Count3
        End If
    Next Count3

    Set xrng = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    Set Temp1 = Range("AR1", Range("AR1").End(xlDown))
    Set Temp2 = Range("AS1", Range("AS1").End(xlDown))
    Set Temp3 = Range("AT1", Range("AT1").End(xlDown))

    DataSheet.Activate

    Dim Chart1 As Chart
    Set Chart1 = Charts.Add
```

This is the code that works but when I add it to go all the way to ChartCells36 it crashes

I expect to get 3 values stored per column but I can't get the  code to work

Comment: When it crashes, do you get any errors? Can you describe how you can't get the code to work?

Comment: Microsoft stops responding and then just closes so no error messages or anything

Comment: Also, what's "ChartCells36"? Are you just looping through ranges and doing the same thing? If so, you should look in to rewriting the code to be more [DRY](https://olusolaoguntuberu.com/guidelines-maintainable-excel-vba-code/), so you can make more relative references.

Comment: Yes I  just want to  do the same thing through 36 different columns I just don't know how to do that as I am very new to VBA